# Get common cookies value for different paths

Tags: angularjs, cookies, jquery-cookie

In my project i am using ng-cookies to store the user's id in browser. I log in through user name and password using this url `mysite.com/myproject/`. All other url's in my project come after `/myproject/`.

E.g: `mysite.com/myproject/adduser.html/`

Problem is :

I can login through either `mysite.com/myproject/` or `mysite.com/myproject/login.html` (both will redirect to login page only).

When i login through `mysite.com/myproject/` then the cookies set only on this url so if i try to redirect `mysite.com/myproject/login.html` -cookies are empty.

How can i get cookies values for different url paths in same project and non empty cookie values? why always sets the cookie path to the current page?